# Как правильно задействовать REGEX в Ruby

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

```
(irb):1:REGEX_FSU_6 = /(?<MessageName>FSU)\/(?<VersionNumber>6)\s+(?<ShAirline_code>\d{2})-(?<ShAwb>\d{8})(?<ShOrigin>\S{3})(?<ShDestination>\S{3})\/(?<ShPartsCode>[TP])(?<ShPieces>\d+)(?<ShWeightCode>[KL])(?<ShWeight>\d+\.?\d*?)(<MvStatusCode>\S{3})\/(<MvAirline>\w{2})(?<MvFlightNumber>\w{1,3})\/(<MvDeparture>)\/(<MvOrigin>\w{3})(<MvDestination>\w{3})\/(?<MvPartsCode>[TP])(?<MvPieces>\d+)(?<MvWeightCode>[KL])(?<MvWeight>\d+\.?\d*?)/
(irb):2:body = 'FSU/6
123-87654321FRASVX/T1K6.4
PRE/U6702/28FEB/PRGSVX/T1K6.4' #=> "FSU/6\n123-87654321FRASVX/T1K6.4\nPRE/U6702/28FEB/PRGSVX/T1K6.4"
(irb):3:data = body.match(REGEX_FSU_6) #=> nil
(irb):4: data['ShAirline_code'] #=> undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно в строке `(irb):3:` вызвать константу `REGEX_FSU_6`, что бы я из `body` мог вытянуть любое значение по типу как в строке `(irb):4:`?

Comment: Тут, очевидно, проблема не в вызове функции. Регулярное выражение не подходит к body.

Comment: Тоже так подумал. Сижу сейчас разбираюсь. Только начал разбираться с регулярками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REGEX_FSU_6 = /
  (?<MessageName>FSU)\/(?<VersionNumber>6)\s+
  (?<ShAirline_code>\d{2,3})-(?<ShAwb>\d{8})(?<ShOrigin>\S{3})(?<ShDestination>\S{3})\/(?<ShPartsCode>[TP])(?<ShPieces>\d+)(?<ShWeightCode>[KL])(?<ShWeight>\d+(\.\d+)?)\s+
  (?<MvStatusCode>\S{3})\/(?<MvAirline>[\dA-Z]{2})(?<MvFlightNumber>\d{1,3})\/(?<MvDeparture>\d{1,2}[A-Z]{3})\/(?<MvOrigin>[A-Z]{3})(?<MvDestination>[A-Z]{3})\/(?<MvPartsCode>[TP])(?<MvPieces>\d+)(?<MvWeightCode>[KL])(?<MvWeight>\d+(\.\d+)?)
/x

data = body.match REGEX_FSU_6

puts data["ShAirline_code"]
```